# Show that function is not bounded.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

How to show that function $$f(x,y)=\sqrt[k]{\frac{x^2+y^2-2x}{2(y+k)-x^2-y^2}}$$ where k is a finite, positive, real number, is not bounded?
The only thing I could think of is to find a counterexample but so far I failed to do so. Hints?

Comment: Is $k$ positive?

Comment: Yes it is positive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$f(x,0)=\sqrt[k]{\frac{x^2-2x} {2k-x^2 }   }  $$ and
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow (-\sqrt{2k})^{+}}f(x,0)=+\infty  \qquad  \text{being } k>0$$